# Place a label at coordinates in Titanium

Tags: label, titanium, coordinates, titanium-mobile

I have created a label and would like to place it on certain coordinates. Is there a way I can directly set the x and y coordinates to place the label in Titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, just set the `top` and `left` values to to your respective Y and X values. These are relative to the labels parent, and will not work as expected if you set the parents `layout` property to anything but `composite`:

```
var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  color: '#900',
  font: { fontSize:48 },
  text: 'A simple label',
  textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
  top: 30, // Your Y coordinate
  left : 20, // Your X coordinate
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
```

[Check this guide for more information](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy) about views, and positioning.